# CMake OpenSSL trouble porting a cpp app from OSX to Ubuntu

Tags: c++, cmake, openssl

As it says in the title, I'm porting an OSX C++ application to Ubuntu. This app works perfectly on OSX, but is failing to compile on Ubuntu. Here is my CMake - it is a little weird because I set up the structure so I can swap toolchains in CLion to compile for both platforms:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)


set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR /Users/home/cpp_libraries/openssl@1.1)

set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME OFF)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
set(BOOST_ROOT /Users/home/cpp_libraries/boost_1_80_0)
set(Boost_INCLUDE_DIR /Users/home/cpp_libraries/boost_1_80_0)
set(Boost_LIB_DIR /Users/home/cpp_libraries/boost_1_80_0/libs)

include_directories(/Users/home/cpp_libraries/openssl@1.1/include)
include_directories(/Users/home/cpp_libraries/boost_1_80_0)
include_directories(/Users/home/cpp_libraries/boost_1_80_0/boost/beast)
include_directories(/Users/home/cpp_libraries/boost_1_80_0/boost/asio)
include_directories(/Users/home/cpp_libraries/boost_1_80_0/boost/json)
include_directories(/Users/home/cpp_libraries/boost_1_80_0/boost/ssl)

include_directories(/Users/home/cpp_libraries/for-redis-2.8/)
link_directories(/usr/local/include/)

include_directories(/Users/home/cpp_libraries/hiredis/1.2.0/include/hiredis/)
link_directories(/Users/home/cpp_libraries/hiredis/1.2.0/include/hiredis/)
include_directories(/usr/local/include/)
link_directories(/usr/local/include/)
link_directories(/usr/local/lib64/)


link_directories(/usr/include)
link_directories(/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/liblibev.a)
include_directories(/Users/home/cpp_libraries/libev/4.33/include/)
link_directories(/Users/home/cpp_libraries/libev/4.33/include/)
link_directories(/usr/local/include/redox/)

add_executable(openssl_test main.cpp)

find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED)
message(STATUS "OpenSSL: Version ${OPENSSL_VERSION}")
message(STATUS "OpenSSL: include dir at ${OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR}")
message(STATUS "OpenSSL: libraries at ${OPENSSL_LIBRARIES} ${OPENSSL_SSL_LIBRARIES}")

project(openssl_test)

target_link_libraries(openssl_test libev hiredis redox OpenSSL::SSL OpenSSL::Crypto)
```

All packages are at the specified locations. The compiler command is: `/usr/bin/cmake --build /tmp/tmp.qdeVu03ayC/cmake-build-debug --target bybit_feed -- -j 6`

When I try to compile this on Ubuntu, I get a cascade of undefined symbol errors, for example:

```
usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/openssl_test.dir/main.cpp.o: in function `session::on_resolve(boost::system::error_code, boost::asio::ip::basic_resolver_results<boost::asio::ip::tcp>)':
/tmp/tmp.qdeVu03ayC/main.cpp:213: undefined reference to `SSL_ctrl
```

What am I doing wrong in my CMake preventing OpenSSL from being correctly linked on Ubuntu?

Comment: Lots of questions on this topic, but there doesn't seem to be any directly addressing the changes needed to port between these platforms so seemed appropriate to ask.

Comment: While it's OK to give the absolute and user-dependent paths to variables like `BOOST_ROOT`, it is a bad practice to do the same with `include` or `link` directories. You should use `find_package`, and then use exported variables `PACKAGENAME_INCLUDE_DIRS` etc. or exported targets like `target_include_directories(MyApp Package::component)`.

Comment: @pptaszni noted! I'm following that paradigm you suggest in the OpenSSL bit at the bottom - does the way I'm linking it look correct for Ubuntu there? Going nuts trying to figure out why its not finding the package/linking it.

Comment: As for your particular linker errors, check if  `OPENSSL_LIBRARIES` is pointing to the correct location. [Here is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix) a generic topic on resolving undefined references. Useful commands: `ldd ./myApp` to see unresolved shared libs, `nm -D /usr/lib/SOME_LIB.so` to see if the symbol that you need actually exists.

Comment: @Tsyvarev edited

Comment: My guess would be that you're compiling against `/Users/home/cpp_libraries/openssl@1.1/include` but `find_package` is linking against the system libraries. Either use `include_directories` or link to the `find_package` targets, not both at the same time